# Does boiling or frying fish make Omega3 be denatured?

Tags: food

I read some articles about omega-3, and I found there are two different opinions about how sensitive omega-3 is to heat. one is Applying heat to omega-3 make omega-3 become trans-isomer which is very bad for the body. and the other is Applying heat to omega-3 doesn't make omega-3 become any bad compound. I want to know which is true. I think maybe Applying heat to omega-3 make trans-fatty acid, but I want to know exact temperature. and what about boilling or frying fish? Wiil applying heat to fish make trans-fatty acid too?